# aws iot file transfer

Tags: mqtt, file-transfer, beagleboneblack, aws-iot

I am trying to use AWS IoT to communicate with my beaglebone board, I got the MQTT messages transferring from the board to the server using MQTT. I was wondering if there is a way to transfer files (text or binary) files to the server and from the server to beaglebone using AWS IoT.

Comment: I saw the Createstream function in the AWS IoT webpage, but could not understand how to use it. Could not find any examples either, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The payload of a MQTT message is just a byte stream, so can carry just about anything (up to the max size of 268,435,456 bytes according to the spec [AWS may have other limits in it's implementation]).

You will have to implement your own code to publish files and to subscribe and save files. You will also have to implement a payload format that includes any metadata you might need (e.g. file names)

Comment: Thanks @hardillb for your response on my question, I am new to AWS IoT and not sure how to use it for sending text files of ~1MB to the server and back to device.
MQTT is the only protocol that I see in the AWS IoT portal, if there is any other protocol please suggest me. 
I saw a function called create stream on (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/api-com.amazonaws.iot.streaming.CreateStream.html), I am not sure how to use it to send files that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer file using MQTT, but you should first divide it to smaller pieces and then send it, but the payload has limitations 128 kB. More information about AWS IoT and its limitations [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#iot-protocol-limits).

But I would suggest not using MQTT to transfer files, because messaging also cost money, so if the file size is big and you send it periodically, then it may cost you much. You can find AWS IoT Core prices [here](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/pricing/?nc1=h_ls).
You can upload your file(s) to S3 bucket and then access the file(s) from there.